# Is it possible to turn off all echo to stdout in PHP?

Tags: php, echo, stdout

I don't want *any* text to be printed to stdout that's not explicitly inside printf or such, and that includes all text outside `<?php ?>` tags. Is that possible? Preferably, I don't want to repeatedly destroy the output buffer with `ob_end_clean`, but rather just turn it off completely and kill all automatic echo.

Edit: I think my main problem is that echo, printf, and text outside `<?php ?>` tags all write to the same buffer. Is that correct?

Update 2: All that's not inside php tags is an implicit echo, which is easy to check on 3v4l opcodes.

Comment: Maybe answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554147/disable-echo-and-print-in-php

Comment: PHP obviously cannot control what is happening _outside_ the opening and closing tags ...

Comment: This sounds a bit like a classical XY problem. As if you are asking how you might achieve something that you think might solve your actual problem, instead of you directly asking how to solve your actual problem ...

Comment: @arkascha The use-case is esoteric. I'm jumping in and out of `<?php ?>` and it seems like PHP keeps flushing or creating output buffers automatically.

Comment: Then PHP is not the language of your choice. PHP is a template engine itself.

Comment: `ob_end_clean` does not just flush the output buffer it should also be ending output buffering completely, unless `ob_start` started while another `ob_start` was also active

Answer (score 0):

fwrite does not buffer when writing to stdout opened from fopen. That makes it possible to turn off all output buffering for PHP with ob_end_clean, and still being able to write to stdout (or any socket) independent of the implicit echo and output buffer.

Edit: Another possible solution suggested by Krzysiek: Using chunk size 1 at ob_start:

```php
<?php

const OUTPUT_PREFIX = "!";

function debug($msg) : void {
    fwrite(STDOUT, sprintf("[Debug] %s\n", $msg));
}

ob_start(function ($buffer) {
    debug("New data buffered: \"{$buffer}\"");
    if(str_starts_with($buffer, OUTPUT_PREFIX)) {
        return substr($buffer, strlen(OUTPUT_PREFIX));
    }
    return null;
}, 1);

echo "Silent echo\n";

function main()
{
    //?>
    this is silent
    //<?php
    fwrite(STDOUT, "This is shown\n");
    //?>
    this is also silent
    <?php
}

printf("!Loud %s\n", "printf");

//?>
//<?php main(); ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Are you concerned about the PHP CLI SAPI specifically? See then as well the `STDOUT`  constant it [spares you the fopen() call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) and there is also [`php://stdout`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) and [`php://output`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.output) which goes to the output buffer (if enabled).

Comment: @hakre Oh yeah, that one also sidesteps the output buffer. Nice, thanks. :)

Comment: If you'd have shared more what you're trying to do it might be possible to give better tips, in general HTML, `<?= ... ?>`, `echo`, `print`, `printf`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, `var_export(x, false)` etc. all go to `php://output`  by default. `fwrite`, `fprintf` etc. - everything that takes a stream handle - you can write directly to a stream (e.g. STDOUT) . if you're specifically concerned about the HTML part (everything outside `<?php ... ?>` ) you can also interfere PHP loading the file and blank out those parts. But better share more about what you're trying to do first.

Comment: And the implicit buffer depends on PHP ini configuration: https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

Comment: Thanks @hakre . The use-case is about polyglot code, so it's quite esoteric/code-golfy. ^^ Despite being a professional PHP developer for 10 years, I didn't know about implicit echo and fwrite not being buffered. So you learn something new every day!